# Javascript validation : compare string in dropdown list with other column in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to make a validation form before submitting a form. In my case my data is in a table like this:

```
<form name ="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="generateSchedule" class="sky-form">
  <header><br><center>Generate Schedule</center></header>
     <center>
        <fieldset>  
           <section>
            <label class="select">

              <% //Connection to db
                 String query="select s.studentID, s.studentName,s.projecttitle,s.lecturerID, l.lecturerID, l.lecturerFullname from student s JOIN lecturer l ON s.lecturerID = l.lecturerID where ROWNUM<=30";
                 ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
                 int i=1;
              %>
             <table id="t01">
              <tr>
              <th>No.</th>
              <th>Student name</th>
              <th>Project title</th>
              <th>Supervisor name</th>
              <th>Examiner </th>
              </tr>
              <% while(rs.next()){ %>
              <tr>
              <td><%= i++ %>.</td>
              <td>
              <input type="hidden" name="studentID" style="" value=<%=rs.getString("studentID") %>">
              <%=rs.getString("studentName") %>
              </td>
              <td><%= rs.getString("projectTitle") %></td>
              <td>
              <input id="supervisor" type="hidden" name="supervisorID" style="" value="<%=rs.getString("lecturerID") %>">                                           <%=rs.getString("lecturerFullname")%>
              </td>
              <td>
              <select id="examinerID" name="examinerID" onchange="checkLecturer()">
              <option selected disabled>Examiners Name</option>
              <%
                try{ //Connection to db again
                    String query1="select lecturerID, lecturerFullname from lecturer ";
                    ResultSet rs1=stmt1.executeQuery(query1);
                    while(rs1.next())
                    { %>

              <option value="<%=rs1.getString("lecturerID") %>">           <%=rs1.getString("lecturerFullname") %></option>
                 <% }
                    //closing connection }
                    catch (Throwable theException) {
                    //exception statement  } %></select>

              </td></tr>
               <% }
                //close connection again }
             catch (Throwable lln) {
                 //catch statement}     
               %>
              </table>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button"> Generate schedule</button><br><br>
           </center>
         </label>
    </section>
</fieldset></center>
```

I am sorry the codes are long and messy because I am still new at this. I am aware it is not good to combine JAVA in JSP.

Based on above codes, the column `student name`, `project title` and `supervisor name` comes from the first query. Then in `examiner` column, there will be drop down menu dynamically generated using second query.

This is how it looks like. Sorry I had to blur out the data:

[image]

The Javascript:

```
 <script>
                        function validateForm() {
                            return checkLecturer();
                        }

                        function checkLecturer() {

                            var ex = document.forms["myForm"]["examiner"].value;
                            var sv = document.forms["myForm"]["supervisor"].value;

                            if (sv === ex) {

                                document.getElementById("examiner").className = 'error';
                                return false;
                            } 
                            else {
                                document.getElementById("examiner").className = '';
                                return true;
                            }
                        }  

        </script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
 .error {
                border:1px solid red;
            }
</style>
```

I want the form dropdown list for `examinerID` turns red if the user choose same value of `supervisorID`. I am wondering why my codes is not working..

*UPDATE 16 MAY 2016*

[image]

I am copying the same exact code as you what you did... It worked perfectly...

[image]

@Ansari answer still getting blue border

Comment: That's because `onkeyup` event for `select-options` doesn't exist.. Attach `onchange` event on `select` instead..

Comment: remove `onkeyup="checkLecturer()"` too?

Comment: It isnt working @GuruprasadRao...

Comment: Wait. Am preparing you the solution..

Comment: After selecting same value are you submitting the form by clicking on submit

Answer (score 0):

There were lot of things which is **`erroneous`** in your case, which are as below:

- `select` elements `option` tag does not have `id` and `onkeyup` *`attributes/events`*. They can have only **[`below 4 attributes`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp)** and few **[`global events as attributes`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)**:
  [image: Option Attributes]
- You cannot have same `ids` for different elements. `id` has to be unique per page. In your case you had it in `option` tags.
- `CSS` styles works for `option` tag only on few browsers. So if you want to achieve it completely you can use `select` `jquery` plugins which are numerously present in google when you search, which will have plenty of options/features to set. Otherwise you have to include any `element` to display your error messages.
- You need to get the `selected` value from `select` element which will not work with `document.forms["myForm"]["examiner"].value;`, because of above reasons.
- You haven't closed your `<table>` element. Not sure if this is the **copy paste** issue.

Below is the solution that I would suggest according to your requirements, few modified..

```js
 function validateForm() {
     return checkLecturer();
 }

 function checkLecturer() {

     var e = document.getElementById("examinerID");
  var ex = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
     var sv = document.forms["myForm"]["supervisor"].value;
  if (sv === ex) {
         document.getElementById("examiner").className = 'error';
   document.getElementById("examiner").style.display = 'block';           
         return false;
     } else {
      document.getElementById("examiner").style.display = 'none';           
         document.getElementById("examiner").className = '';
         return true;
     }
 }
```

```css
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="generateSchedule" class="sky-form">
  <table id="t01">
    <tr>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Student name</th>
      <th>Project title</th>
      <th>Supervisor name</th>
      <th>Examiner</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>1.</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>def</td>
      <td>
        <input id="supervisor" type="hidden" name="supervisorID" value="Kent" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="examinerID" id="lecturerFullname" onchange="checkLecturer()">
          <option value="Suzy">Suzy</option>
          <option value="Kent">Kent</option>
          <option value="John">John</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button name="submit" class="button">SUBMIT</button>
  <div id="examiner" style="display:none">
    Both are same
  </div>
</form>
```

## [`Here is the external fiddle solution`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/rofydj70/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I tried and it is not working :( (still working on it) BTW i wanted the border to change to red..

Comment: You mean `border` of `option` element?

Comment: Yes :) Is it possible if it did not working because i did it one html page?

Comment: It detects the same value through `value="Kent"` right?

Comment: what if the value is dynamic. For example,  `<option value="<%=rs1.getString("lecturerID") %>">`

Comment: Dynamic values too work, but you need to ensure you have exact case sensitive values. Also, as I said earlier you cannot style option elements..

Comment: What should I do if i styled my `option`. Oh wait.. what do you mean by style my option elements

Comment: I might need to see then.. Can you post a screenshot..??

Comment: I am sorry for replying this late. Which screenshot would you like to see?

Comment: Updated my question. BTW would you like to see the real HTML codes where including the scriplets?

Comment: Sure pls.. As I said, I don't think you can style `select` elements with `css`.. That's where plugins comes into picture..

Comment: Updated :) I am sorry its messy

Comment: Are you using any extension or plugin for `select`?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you mean other javascript for select?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
 Test
</title>
    <style>
        .error {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        return checkLecturer();
    }

    function checkLecturer() {
        var e = document.getElementById("examinerID");
        var ex = e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

        var sv = document.forms["myForm"]["supervisorID"].value;

        if (sv === ex) {

            document.getElementById('ddldiv').className = "error";
            alert("you can\'t select " + ex);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('ddldiv').className = "";
            return true;
        }
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('examinerID').onchange = function () {
            checkLecturer();
        };
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>    
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="generateSchedule" class="sky-form">
        <table id="t01">
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Student name</th>
                <th>Project title</th>
                <th>Supervisor name</th>
                <th>Examiner </th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1.</td>
                <td>abc</td>
                <td>def</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="supervisor" type="hidden" name="supervisorID" value="Kent" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="ddldiv" style="width: 150px; height: 22px;">
                        <select name="examinerID" id="lecturerFullname" style="width: 150px; height: 30px;">
                            <option id="examiner" onkeyup="checkLecturer()">Suzy</option>
                            <option id="examiner" onkeyup="checkLecturer()">Kent</option>
                            <option id="examiner" onkeyup="checkLecturer()">John</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Submit"  />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

use this `e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML` in place of `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value` as value is null or not defined.

so try this script:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        return checkLecturer();
    }

    function checkLecturer() {
        var e = document.getElementById("examinerID");
        var ex = e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

        var sv = document.forms["myForm"]["supervisorID"].value;

        if (sv === ex) {

            document.getElementById('ddldiv').className = "error";
            alert("you can\'t select " + ex);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('ddldiv').className = "";
            return true;
        }
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('examinerID').onchange = function () {
            checkLecturer();
        };
    };
</script>
```

and use this HTML

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="generateSchedule" class="sky-form">
        <table id="t01">
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Student name</th>
                <th>Project title</th>
                <th>Supervisor name</th>
                <th>Examiner </th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>1.</td>
                <td>abc</td>
                <td>def</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="supervisor" type="hidden" name="supervisorID" value="Kent" /></td>
                <td>
                    <div id="ddldiv" style="width:150px;height:22px;">
                        <select name="examinerID" id="lecturerFullname" style="width:150px;height:30px;">
                            <option id="examiner" onkeyup="checkLecturer()">Suzy</option>
                            <option id="examiner" onkeyup="checkLecturer()">Kent</option>
                            <option id="examiner" onkeyup="checkLecturer()">John</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button">SUBMIT </button>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: @user6308605 have you used my html also?

Comment: @user6308605 make sure this css `<style>
        .error {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>` is there

Comment: added below `</head>` still not functioning hmm

Comment: @user6308605 i just added my entire html have a look.

Comment: @user6308605 to test you can copy entire html to a notepad and save as somename.html make sure while saving all files is selected and open in a browser to test this

Comment: The result should be showing red border for dropdown menu if i choose Kent right? This is because it is the same value as supervisor right?

Comment: @user6308605 it you select `kent` from dropdown it will show red border to dropdown. this is what you need?

Comment: @user6308605 so the html i pasted it is doing the same, so this solves your problem?

Comment: @user6308605 I added output also it is working fine, must be something wrong on your end, you are using IE(internet Explorer) only?

Comment: I am using Chrome :(

Comment: @user6308605 submit the form then it will show red border

Comment: @user6308605 if you want on change then call the script like this window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("examinerID").onchange=function() { validateForm();
    }};

Comment: @user6308605 just add this script in your script section, if you want red border to appear on dropdown change event

Comment: @user6308605 I think you must be celebrating April fool in May

Comment: I am not :( Its fine Ill figure why.. sorry

Comment: @user6308605 i modified `javascript` use my javascript and `html` and try now, let me know if it works.

Comment: @user6308605 just below the image i added there is html starting from `<html>` and end at `</html>` copy entire html and save it as html file(open notepad paste and save with somename.html but make sure All Files is selected while saving) and open this file in IE(internet explorer) it should 100% work for sure.